# $ not working in regex in Scala

Tags: scala

Am I correct that `$` is used to match an expression starting from end of a string (opposite to`^` which matches from beginning of the string)?

The `^` is working fine

```
scala> val reg = "^(abc)".r
reg: scala.util.matching.Regex = ^(abc)

scala> reg findFirstIn "hello abc hanu"
res44: Option[String] = None

scala> reg findFirstIn "abc hello abc hanu"
res45: Option[String] = Some(abc)
```

But `$` isn't

```
scala> val reg = "$(abc)".r
reg: scala.util.matching.Regex = $(abc)

scala> reg findFirstIn "abc hello abc hanu"
res46: Option[String] = None

scala> reg findFirstIn "abc hello abc hanu abc"
res47: Option[String] = None
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$` matches end of input, so `$(abc)` means go to the end of the input, then find `abc` after the end.  This obviously would never match anything.

Did you maybe mean `(abc)$` meaning find `(abc)` just before the end (instead of after)?